# Tag synonym request: [upgrading] -> [upgrade]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think the new tag [upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upgrading) should be made a synonym of [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upgrade).

I've [proposed the tag synonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/upgrade/synonyms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been done. Thank you for your attention to detail.